# sqlite3 NOT NULL constraint failed despite specific not null value

Tags: sql, sqlite

despite none `NULL` value in column `preptime2` (value = 7), SQLite is throwing exception:

> NOT NULL constraint failed.

The excerpt below is showing

(1) value in `menucard_meal.preptime2` (value = 7)

and then

(2) the try to `INSERT INTO` same data in table orders_meal which throws the error.

```
sqlite> select preptime2 from menucard_meal where id = 32;
7
sqlite> INSERT INTO orders_meal SELECT * from menucard_meal where id = 32;
Error: NOT NULL constraint failed: orders_meal.preptime2
sqlite>
```

Has someone any idea what happens here? Thnx

Answer (score 1):

In this statement:

```
INSERT INTO orders_meal 
SELECT * from menucard_meal 
where id = 32;
```

there are 2 tables involved: `orders_meal` and `menucard_meal`.
In the above statement you do not list the columns of either table.
This is not required but it is a good practice and usually it saves you from problems like (I suspect) this one.
List the columns for both tables and make sure that the corresponding columns are in the same order, like:

```
INSERT INTO orders_meal(column1, column2, columnforpreptime2, ...) 
SELECT col1, col2, preptime2, ... 
from menucard_meal 
where id = 32;
```